# MS Azure SQL - How to restrict User to one [custom] schema without the ability to access [sys] and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA]

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I've performed the following:

- created a new [custom] schema on the [customer_db]
- created new [login] & [user] in the [master] and corresponding user
  in the [customer_db]
- granted 'db_datareader' and 'db_denydatawriter' to [user]
- `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::custom TO [user]`
- `DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [user]`
- `DENY SELECT ON schema::[sys] TO [user]`
- `DENY SELECT ON schema::[INFORMATION_SCHEMA] TO [user]`

...but when I am trying this new, restricted login it still allows me to see all the [sys] and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA] related tables & views

[image]

I've also tried:

```
DENY SELECT, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[sys] to [user];
GO
DENY SELECT, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[INFORMATION_SCHEMA] to [user];
GO
```

This also completed successfully but it took no effect as well.

How can I restrict specific user to a specific schema only without [sys] and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA] listings?

**Note/Update:**
The DENY VIEW SERVER STATE TO [user]; returns:

```
Msg 40520, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Comment: Can you try this:deny VIEW DATABASE STATE to user

Comment: Just tried DENY VIEW DATABASE STATE to [User]. It executed successfully but made no difference.

Comment: To be clear: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: The security model has changed **significantly** since SQL 2000 (I'd _highly_ recommend choosing a newer version).

Additionally, how are you configuring your linked server?

Comment: @drediske - I am running on Azure (which is v. 2012) but the linked server is being created on many different systems which can range as far as SQL2000. I think you got it the other way. The restrictions I need to set properly are on the Azure SQL server not the SQL2000 or any other. Thx.

Comment: @Milan - are you able to actually `SELECT` on those views?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have an install of SQL 2000 handy, but working off of a modern version of SSMS and a local SQL Server linked to an Azure SQL DB I was able to see some things which may shed some light:

First off: SQL Server in Azure mimics *as closely as possible* the behaviors of the on premise versions of SQL Server. It appears that the catalog of views that you showed is available for the permission level of the login we created; I may not have reproduced the exact circumstances, but I was able to see the existence of system views when my permissions should, in theory, have been restricting them from my view. This seems to go against the spirit of the concept of permissions.

However, this is not unprecedented:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Will return master & the current database. (Try it with your restricted permissions- it should still succeed, even though it's technically a sys view).

Yet, a similar query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

Throws an expected error (... The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'objects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.).

Now, if you're able to select from any/all views listed, this is an entirely different behavior and contradicts the permission entirely.

[This was also examined partially in this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25667/deny-access-to-information-schema-in-sql-server) , [this one involving sys views specifically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25671/security-question-involving-sys-tables), and [has a bit of documentation on MSDN too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx).

EDIT: [Here's one more on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA specifically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25667/deny-access-to-information-schema-in-sql-server)

Comment: Great insight! I could not select from any sys.[] - returns (The SCHEMA LOCK permission was denied on the object 'system_views', database 'mydatabase', schema 'sys'.) but I am able to select from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA]

Comment: So it was ineffective on restricting access to Information_schema? Check out the info at the link I edited at the end and see if that helps.

Comment: ..yes I found that one too. It denies the SELECT but still keeps the views and tables listed. I do not thing there is an easy solution to this but  I am going to wait a little to see if anyone else will contribute the "perfect" solution. Many thanks!

Comment: @Milan ,  
What information do you think you're leaking by having these tables visible in SSMS? (Or, more specifically, what is the purpose of this question?)

Comment: The purpose of the question was to find out how to accomplish a total isolation of one (custom) schema user from the rest of Azure DB. An isolated user who has permission to [custom] schema only should not see any other schema regardless of what it is or if any sensitive information is leaked or not - is simply does not seem clean.

Comment: @Milan I agree- it doesn't seem very clean. Thanks for helping me understand your inquiry better!